# How to configure iscsi offloading on centos 7

Tags: centos, iscsi

Could someone explain how to configure iscsi offloading on Centos7.

We have this nic card Hewlett-Packard Company FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 533FLR-T Adapter, it's based upon Broadcom Limited NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet.

It's a two ports 10Gbe nic card, and it supports iscsi offload.
The card has it's own BIOS entry.

From reading about iscsi offloading, I did understand that we can use this functionality to get better performance, since it uses the card itself to handle the iscsi stuff.

the iscsiadm -m iface command gives this 
bnx2i.ec:b1:d7:ad:74:29 bnx2i,ec:b1:d7:ad:74:29,,,
bnx2i.ec:b1:d7:ad:74:2d bnx2i,ec:b1:d7:ad:74:2d,,,

the corresponding Ethernet ports of these two entries are :
eno49 with MAC : ec:b1:d7:ad:74:28  and
eno50 with MAC : ec:b1:d7:ad:74:2c

My question is how to configure iscsi offload? since I need both : the Ethernet port using tcp transport for discovery and the iscsi port using the bnx2i transport for iscsi traffic, if I am not wrong.

- Do I have to give the iscsi port and IP address from the BIOS?
- if yes, does it have to be the same as the Ethernet port corresponding?
- How to I link between the iscsi port and the Ethernet port from the iscsi perspective?

It's not clear from the RHEL documentation.

Regards.